# F-test comparing the variances of two in/dependent variables

Tags: variance, independence, f-test

I have 64 time meausures at morning, and 64 measures at evening.

I would like to use F-test, to compare  variances of my times (are my times equally "stable" at morning an evening?). All time measures are made on me. F-test assumptions are, that samples are normally distributed and independent. I am little bit confused, but is this "dependent case"? If yes, which test should I use for comparing variances?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a matter of modeling. For most applications, we would model all data measured on the same individual as dependent. This dependency is often (mixed effect ANOVA models) modeled by some kind of "individual effect" that is somehow added to the independent time effects.

In your case, there is only one individual (you). If we can model your data with such an additive individual effect, it will cancel by in calculating variances so that the test for equal variances is not concerned. However, if you believe that such an individual effect is multiplicative, it will make variance comparison impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Pitman's variance ratio test for correlated samples, may be good for you. It doesn't assume any dependency between samples. There is just a correction for correlation in test formula.

Comment: Pitman's test uses pearson correlation, which needs some pairs to measure correlations. But I don't have this type of data. Different shuffles leads to different results.