# Paired non-parametric test for a difference in variance

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova, variance, paired-data

I have $N = 391$ paired data points $\mathbf a = a_1, \ldots a_N$ and $\mathbf b = b_1, \ldots b_N$.

Both $\mathbf a$ and $\mathbf b$ are approximately normally distributed with a mean of zero.

I want to test the null hypothesis that $\text{Var}(\mathbf a) \geq \text{Var}(\mathbf b)$ against the alternative hypothesis that $\text{Var}(\mathbf a) < \text{Var}(\mathbf b)$.

Is there a suitable test for this?

I am thinking maybe I could draw bootstrap samples, compute the variance each time, and then do a difference of means test?

Comment: If you believe the population means are zero you could perhaps compare the ratio of the corresponding squared values to 1 i.e. compute $R_i=B_i^2/A_i^2$ and test an alternative hypothesis that some aspect of the distribution of the ratio (perhaps its mean) exceeds 1; you might be able to use a permutation test. I don't see any simple way of dealing with the pairing besides something more or less along those lines. If you ignore the pairing, you can do a few things.

Comment: This question may be of interest: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/841/comparing-the-variance-of-paired-observations.

Comment: Meant to mention -- but space didn't permit -- that you have to be careful about whether my suggestion for accounting for pairing really corresponds to your actual hypothesis of interest (I was assuming a degree of vagueness in the expression of it in the question that would permit this difference when more carefully considered).

Comment: $a, b$ are independent or not? Please clarify be editing your post!  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/286932/f-test-comparing-the-variances-of-two-in-dependent-variables, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/621786/statistically-comparing-the-variance-of-two-dependent-samples