# Statistically comparing the variance of two dependent samples

Tags: hypothesis-testing, variance, levenes-test

I have two dependent samples of data. Each sample contains *N = 800 values* (data points) and stem from the same human subjects, that is, *sample one* is the pre-experimental and *sample two* the post-experimental group of the same 800 subjects.

**Aim:** I am not interested in comparing the two groups’ mean for statistical significance, but their variance or, more generally, the distribution in sample one vs. sample two.

**Question:** I assume that a the **Levene test** (in case the samples are approximately normally distributed) or the **Brown-Forsythe test** (in case the samples lack normality) would be the right choice.

I am not interested in checking the data for parametric test assumptions (such as homogeneity of variance) because I would like to apply a t-Test later, but because I am interested in potentially different variances between both samples.

Are there better tests for my aim, or are the two suggested tests just fine in my case?

Comment: One classical example is the Pitman-Morgan test. Rand Wilcox discusses this test in [this paper](https://jsdajournal.springeropen.com/articles/10.1186/s40488-015-0030-z) and proposes a robust alternative.

Comment: Interesting, I never heard about the Pitman-Morgen test. I will check this one out. Thanks!